# Get tab host from layout of fragment returns in NullPointerException

Tags: android, layout, nullpointerexception, android-tabhost, fragment

Here is the layout for the fragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lytContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include1"
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/lytImage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgRecibeImage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/img5" />


        </FrameLayout>
        <TabHost
            android:id="@+id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtRecibeComment"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </TabWidget>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtRecibeComment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lytImage"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Crispy Chicken and Sandwich Crispy Chicken and Sandwich Crispy Chicken and Sandwich Crispy Chicken and Sandwich "
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the class for the fragment

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    private TextView txtHeaderTitle;
    private TextView txtRecibeComment;
    private LinearLayout lytContainer;
    private ImageView imgRecibeImage;
    private ImageView imgHeader;
    DBHelper db;
    TabHost tabHost;
    Resources res;

    Intent i;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle b) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.recipe, container, false);
        db = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        txtHeaderTitle = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.txtHeaderTitle);
        txtRecibeComment = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.txtRecibeComment);
        lytContainer = (LinearLayout)rl.findViewById(R.id.lytContainer);
        imgRecibeImage = (ImageView) rl.findViewById(R.id.imgRecibeImage);
        imgHeader = (ImageView) rl.findViewById(R.id.imgHeader);
        imgHeader.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //  finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),RecipesListActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        tabHost = (TabHost) container.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

        displayRecipe(getRecipe(getArguments().getInt("id")));
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Method");
        spec.setIndicator(setMyIndictors("طريقة التحضير","L"));
        i = new Intent(getActivity(),MethodActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("rId", getArguments().getInt("id"));
        spec.setContent(i);     
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Ingredients");
        spec.setIndicator(setMyIndictors("مكونات الوصفة","R"));
        i = new Intent(getActivity(),IngredientsActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("rId", getArguments().getInt("id"));
        spec.setContent(i);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

        setTabColor(tabHost);
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
                setTabColor(tabHost);

            }
        });
        return rl;  
    }
```

where the taphost is NULL : and the error is :

```
09-10 22:39:15.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1287): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 22:39:15.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1287):     at mobile.bh.activities.Tab1.setTabColor(Tab1.java:109)
09-10 22:39:15.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1287):     at mobile.bh.activities.Tab1.onCreateView(Tab1.java:82)
09-10 22:39:15.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1287):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
09-10 22:39:15.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1287):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
09-10 22:39:15.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1287):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
09-10 22:39:15.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1287):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
09-10 22:39:15.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1287):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
09-10 22:39:15.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1287):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
09-10 22:39:15.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1287):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:895)
09-10 22:39:15.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1287):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:772)
09-10 22:39:15.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1287):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1234)
09-10 22:39:15.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1287):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
09-10 22:39:15.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1287):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
```